# Full text index population stuck at Starting on SQL 2012

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I have a sql server 2012 box that hosts hundreds of databases. All databases use full text indexing. The indexing has stopped working.

executing this query:

```
SELECT  status_description
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_population
```

returns `status_description` equal to `Starting` for all databases where there has been recent activity.

I created a new database and created a full text index. It has the same problem, the population is not completing.

What can be the cause? Can I somehow reset the full text index *service* without restaring SQL Server service itself?

Comment: Have you check the SQL Server Full-text crawl log?